# Confluence mySQL image doesn't start anymore

Tags: docker, mysql

I am running a confluence container containing an image for the application itself and one for the mySQL db. This was running smoothly until I run the latest Docker update. Since then, the mySQL image is constantly trying to restart, but the start fails.

This is my docker-compose.yml:

```
version: '3'
services:
  confluence:
    build: ./confl_mysql
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - /Users/michimacmini/Confluence/data/confluence:/var/atlassian/application-data/confluence
    ports:
      - 8090:8090
      - 8091:8091
  confl-mysql:
    image: mysql
    restart: always
    command: [mysqld, --character-set-server=utf8mb4, --collation-server=utf8mb4_bin, --transaction-isolation=READ-COMMITTED, --max_allowed_packet=512M, --innodb_log_file_size=2GB]
    environment:
      - MYSQL_RANDOM_ROOT_PASSWORD=yes
      - MYSQL_DATABASE=confluence
      - MYSQL_USER=confluence
      - MYSQL_PASSWORD=mypw
    volumes:
      - /Users/michimacmini/Confluence/data/mysql:/var/lib/mysql
```

And this is what the log says:

```
Most likely, you have hit a bug, but this error can also be caused by malfunctioning hardware.
Thread pointer: 0x0
Attempting backtrace. You can use the following information to find out
where mysqld died. If you see no messages after this, something went
terribly wrong...
stack_bottom = 0 thread_stack 0x46000
/usr/sbin/mysqld(my_print_stacktrace(unsigned char const*, unsigned long)+0x2e) [0x5630e9ffe41e]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(handle_fatal_signal+0x31b) [0x5630e940508b]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0x12730) [0x7f8f50967730]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(gsignal+0x10b) [0x7f8f500447bb]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(abort+0x121) [0x7f8f5002f535]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x342ae53) [0x5630ea4ade53]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x34168e8) [0x5630ea4998e8]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(srv_pre_dd_shutdown()+0x49d) [0x5630ea44b3ad]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x1ec460f) [0x5630e8f4760f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(plugin_foreach_with_mask(THD*, bool (**)(THD*, st_plugin_int*, void*), int, unsigned int, void*)+0x1cf) [0x5630e92cb50f]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(plugin_foreach_with_mask(THD*, bool (*)(THD*, st_plugin_int*, void*), int, unsigned int, void*)+0x1d) [0x5630e92cb71d]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x1de01c1) [0x5630e8e631c1]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x1de4252) [0x5630e8e67252]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(+0x1df027c) [0x5630e8e7327c]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(mysqld_main(int, char**)+0x1e73) [0x5630e8e75d33]
/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6(__libc_start_main+0xeb) [0x7f8f5003109b]
/usr/sbin/mysqld(_start+0x2a) [0x5630e8e5a02a]
The manual page at http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysql/en/crashing.html contains
information that should help you find out what is causing the crash.
2021-01-05 09:43:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.21-1debian10 started.
2021-01-05 09:43:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Switching to dedicated user 'mysql'
2021-01-05 09:43:39+00:00 [Note] [Entrypoint]: Entrypoint script for MySQL Server 8.0.21-1debian10 started.
2021-01-05T09:43:39.950273Z 0 [System] [MY-010116] [Server] /usr/sbin/mysqld (mysqld 8.0.21) starting as process 1
2021-01-05T09:43:39.959740Z 0 [Warning] [MY-010159] [Server] Setting lower_case_table_names=2 because file system for /var/lib/mysql/ is case insensitive
2021-01-05T09:43:39.980489Z 1 [System] [MY-013576] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has started.
2021-01-05T09:43:42.367077Z 1 [System] [MY-013577] [InnoDB] InnoDB initialization has ended.
2021-01-05T09:43:42.383162Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011087] [Server] Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('2') and data dictionary ('0').
2021-01-05T09:43:42.383806Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010020] [Server] Data Dictionary initialization failed.
2021-01-05T09:43:42.384234Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-010119] [Server] Aborting
2021-01-05T09:43:42.384313Z 0 [ERROR] [MY-013183] [InnoDB] Assertion failure: trx0sys.cc:628:UT_LIST_GET_LEN(trx_sys->rw_trx_list) == trx_sys->n_prepared_trx + active_recovered_trxs thread 140302677280768
InnoDB: We intentionally generate a memory trap.
InnoDB: Submit a detailed bug report to http://bugs.mysql.com.
InnoDB: If you get repeated assertion failures or crashes, even
InnoDB: immediately after the mysqld startup, there may be
InnoDB: corruption in the InnoDB tablespace. Please refer to
InnoDB: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/forcing-innodb-recovery.html
InnoDB: about forcing recovery.
```

Anyone has an idea, what I could try?

Thanks
Michael

Comment: have you read the error report closely?

Comment: Thanks for checking the error report. 

Yeah, I read it. As far as I understand, this line is what hints to the actual problem:
2021-01-05T09:43:42.383162Z 1 [ERROR] [MY-011087] [Server] Different lower_case_table_names settings for server ('2') and data dictionary ('0').

Unfortunately I have no clue how to fix it... Can you hint me in the right direction?

Comment: Actually the nudging was already enough. I foud the solution here: stackoverflow.com/a/64150016/1526406 Thanks for helping me to help myself. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I actually found the solution here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/64150016/1526406

Maybe this helps others as well.